# Argument from CSV file to R function not working

Tags: r, dplyr

Argument from .csv file to R function not working.

Tried function below. But got error message as below.

```
> tf1= data.frame(y=c('price'),grp= c('stock'))
> 
> dat= data.frame(price=c(20,12,24,34,12,34,56,88), 
+                 stock=c('fb','fb','fb','fb','ms','ms','ms','ms'))
> 
> my_fun2 <- function(x, num_var, ...)    {
+   group_var <- enquos(...)
+   num_var <- enquo(num_var)
+   
+   x %>%
+     group_by(!!!group_var) %>%
+     mutate(avg = mean(!!num_var), n = n(), 
+            sd = sd(!!num_var), se = sd/sqrt(n))}
> 
> dat %>% my_fun2(tf1$y,tf1$grp)

price stock `tf1$grp`   avg     n    sd    se
  <dbl> <fct> <fct>     <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1    20 fb    stock        NA     8    NA    NA
2    12 fb    stock        NA     8    NA    NA
3    24 fb    stock        NA     8    NA    NA
4    34 fb    stock        NA     8    NA    NA
5    12 ms    stock        NA     8    NA    NA
6    34 ms    stock        NA     8    NA    NA
7    56 ms    stock        NA     8    NA    NA
8    88 ms    stock        NA     8    NA    NA
```

Warning messages:

> 1: In mean.default(~tf1$y) :   argument is not numeric or logical:
>   returning NA 2: In var(if (is.vector(x) || is.factor(x)) x else
>   as.double(x), na.rm = na.rm) :   Calling var(x) on a factor x is
>   deprecated and will become an error.   Use something like
>   'all(duplicated(x)[-1L])' to test for a constant vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of issues:
First issue is in the definition of the data frame tf1, as is currently set up you are passed factors and not the actual strings.  Need to add `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` to that line.

Second correction, the values from tf1 are now strings which includes the quotes so you do not need the `enquo` function but instead need the `parse_expr` function.  Now this should work as expected.

```
library(rlang)
library(dplyr)

tf1= data.frame(y=c('price'), grp= c('stock'), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
dat= data.frame(price=c(20,12,24,34,12,34,56,88), 
                stock=c('fb','fb','fb','fb','ms','ms','ms','ms'))

my_fun2 <- function(x, num_var, group_var){
  group_var <- parse_expr(group_var)
  num_var <- parse_expr(num_var)

  x %>%
   group_by(!!group_var) %>%
   mutate(avg = mean(!!num_var), n = n(), sd = sd(!!num_var), se = sd/sqrt(n))
}

my_fun2(dat, tf1$y, tf1$grp)


# A tibble: 8 x 6
# Groups:   stock [2]
  price stock   avg     n    sd    se
  <dbl> <fct> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1    20 fb     22.5     4  9.15  4.57
2    12 fb     22.5     4  9.15  4.57
3    24 fb     22.5     4  9.15  4.57
4    34 fb     22.5     4  9.15  4.57
5    12 ms     47.5     4 32.4  16.2 
6    34 ms     47.5     4 32.4  16.2 
7    56 ms     47.5     4 32.4  16.2 
8    88 ms     47.5     4 32.4  16.2
```

**Passing multiple grouping variables**
One option in order to accept multiple grouping variables is to pass a vector of column names.  This does differ from your your initial approach of using the ... arguments.  Passing a vector of names does simplify code greatly.

```
dat= data.frame(price=c(20,12,24,34,12,34,56,88),
                stock=c('fb','fb','fb','fb','ms','ms','ms','ms'),
                day=c("A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B"))

#passing multiple items to the function
my_fun2 <- function(x, num_var, group_var){
  group_var <- parse_exprs(group_var)
  num_var <- parse_expr(num_var)

  x %>%
    group_by(!!!group_var) %>%
    mutate(avg = mean(!!num_var), n = n(), sd = sd(!!num_var), se = sd/sqrt(n))
}

grouping<- c('stock', 'day')
y <- c('price')

my_fun2(dat, y, grouping)
```

Comment: Aim is to get variable names from tf1 not directly from dat . Because I am trying to automate , meaning getting all arguments from values of tf1. These all arguments have corresponding variables in dat. That is where I am not able to resolve variables values from tf1 to variable names of dat.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked as expected. I was struggling for the past 1 week. I  Passed string also. did not not work. because i used enquo instead of parse_expr. Thanks again Dave2e.

Comment: if want to have multiple grouping variables, tried  ...  notation. it is not working. do need to change anything?.

Comment: my_fun2(dat, tf1$y, tf1$grp,tf1$x).  Error in parse_exprs(...) : unused argument (tf1$x). just added 
my_fun2 <- function(x, num_var, ...){
  group_var <- parse_exprs(...)